# Datetime output from Nonetype to Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, nonetype

there. I'm trying to write a webscraper using python and need to first create a column of dates. I've gotten the list I need, but it keeps coming out as NoneType. Any ideas on how to get this to work as a dataframe?

Relevant part of code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
date1 = '2019-01-01'
date2 = '2019-01-30'
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1,'%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2,'%Y-%m-%d')
step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while start <= end:
    daterange = print(start.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    start += step   
type(daterange)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Rachel. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you so much! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
daterange = print(start.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

should be

```
daterange = start.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

EXTRA:
if you want to save the daterange:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
date1 = '2019-01-01'
date2 = '2019-01-30'
daterange_list = []
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1,'%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2,'%Y-%m-%d')
step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while start <= end:
    daterange = start.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    daterange_list.append(daterange)
    start += step   

type(daterange)
str

type(daterange_list) 
list
```